# Fat stationary sets

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Recall a stationary subset $S$ of a regular cardinal $\kappa$ is fat when for every $\alpha < \kappa$, and every club $C$, there is a closed set of order type $\alpha$ contained in $S \cap C$.  It is a result of Stavi, proved [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=716625), that:

(1) For every regular cardinal $\kappa$ and every stationary $S \subseteq \kappa^+ \cap \mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$, $S \cup \mathrm{cf}(<\kappa)$ is fat.

(2) If $S \subseteq \kappa$ is fat, and $2^{<\alpha} < \kappa$ for all $\alpha< \kappa$, then there is a $<\kappa$-distributive forcing of size $2^{<\kappa}$ which forces a club $C \subseteq S$.  Furthermore, the forcing preserves every stationary subset of $S$.

**Questions:** Suppose $\kappa$ is either (a) inaccessible or (b) the successor of singular cardinal. Is it true that there is a sequence of disjoint stationary sets $\langle S_\alpha : \alpha < \kappa \rangle$ and some set $T$ disjoint from all $S_\alpha$ with the following property?  For all clubs $C$, and all $\alpha,\beta < \kappa$, there is a closed subset $p$ of $C \cap (T \cup S_\alpha)$ with order type $\geq \beta$, and $\max p \in S_\alpha$.  An answer under additional combinatorial assumptions (known to be consistent) would be welcome.

Comment: It seems that you want to use this sequence and $T$ to do some forcing. What's the endgame here?

Comment: Code some information into the stationarity/ nonstationarity of some sets.

Comment: Ah. So you essentially want a sequence of fat stationary sets, so you can shoot clubs into them without causing anything to collapse, and thus code information into which sets were shot in the club?

Comment: Yes.  I think this kind of idea is due to Magidor...

Comment: In the work (with Sy Friedman, if my memory serves me right) on getting the number of normal measures to be anything, right?

Comment: That's the one.

Comment: I thought that [that's the one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeoQI-SwI5w). :-) Anyway, I think that you should be able to find a sequence of disjoint or at least almost disjoint fat stationary sets. At least for an inaccessible this sounds like something you can just go by induction and add larger closed intervals to your sets via some bookkeeping. I'm also almost sure that you can force something like that into the world (at least in the inaccessible case).

Comment: Oh yes, I see the forcing now.  It will be equivalent to adding Cohen subset of $\kappa$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose that $\lambda$ is a singular cardinal, $\square_\lambda$ holds, and $2^\lambda=\lambda^+$. Then:

1. There exists a partition of $\lambda^+$ into $\lambda^+$ many pairwise disjoint fat stationary sets.
2. There exists a family of $2^{(\lambda^+)}$ pairwise almost-disjoint fat stationary sets.

Both clauses follow from Theorem D of http://www.assafrinot.com/paper/11 .

An application of Lemma 2.3 of the same paper shows that Clause (1) follows already from $\square_\lambda$ (without the arithmetic hypothesis). 
For $\lambda$ regular, one obtains Clause (1) from $\square(\lambda^+)$ by feeding $\Gamma:=E^{\lambda^+}_\lambda$ to Lemma 3.2 of http://www.assafrinot.com/paper/18 .

Update Jan/2017: http://settheory.mathtalks.org/?p=7240

Comment: How necessary is the square?

Comment: @asaf For Clause (1)? I just need a $\square(\lambda^+)$ sequence for which $\{ \alpha<\lambda^+\mid \text{otp}(C_\alpha)\ge\lambda\}$ is stationary.

Comment: Yes, but can you show that it is consistent without square that no such partition exists?

Comment: Under Martin's Maximum, there cannot be two disjoint fat stationary subsets of $\omega_2$.

Comment: But usually $\omega_2$ is not a successor of singular. At least when assuming MM. :-)

Comment: Correction: I just realized that MM *implies* the existence of $\aleph_2$ many pairwise disjoint fat subsets of $\aleph_2$.

Comment: Okay, so we're back to square one. Pun semi intended.

Comment: Can you at least force something like this at a successor of singular, like you can with an inaccessible?

Comment: @asaf Force what?

Comment: A fat partition.

Comment: Just force square.

Comment: Duh, of course. :-) But can you force one without forcing a square sequence?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think I have a way of forcing this with a $\lambda^+$-closed forcing. This cannot introduce $\square_lambda$.

Comment: @Monroe: That's pretty cool, then. I hope that all in all the fact you can always force it with a "nice" forcing (in the two cases, that is) is sufficient to solve your problem.